# Reading and Writing JSON file Java

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to read a JSON file into a data structure so that I can count a bunch of elements.

The JSON file is of the format `[{String, String, [], String } ... ]`. Now in this array of objects, I need to find the relationship of the first string field (let's say association) to the array field (names of the members). I need to figure out how many associations each of these members belong to.

I'm currently using json-simple and this is how I've done it.

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("c://Users/James McNulty/Documents/School/CMPT 470/Ex 4/exer4-courses.json"));

        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;

        ArrayList<JSONObject> courseInfo = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        Iterator<JSONObject> jsonIterator = jsonArray.iterator();

        while (jsonIterator.hasNext()) {
            courseInfo.add(jsonIterator.next());
            count++;
            //System.out.println(jsonIterator.next());
        }
        //System.out.println(count);

        String course = "";
        String student = "";
        ArrayList<JSONArray> studentsPerCourse = new ArrayList<JSONArray>();
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
            course = (String) courseInfo.get(i).get("course");
            studentsPerCourse.add((JSONArray) courseInfo.get(i).get("students"));
            System.out.println(course);
            System.out.println(studentsPerCourse.get(i));
        }

        ArrayList<String> students = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j< (studentsPerCourse.get(i).size()); j++) {
                students.add((String) studentsPerCourse.get(i).get(j));
                //System.out.println(studentsPerCourse.get(i).get(j));
            }
            //System.out.println(student);
        }

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        Map<String, Integer> studentCourses = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>(students);
        for (String key : unique) {
            studentCourses.put(key, Collections.frequency(students, key));
            object.put(key, Collections.frequency(students, key));
            //System.out.println(key + ": " + Collections.frequency(students, key));   
        }

        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("c://Users/James McNulty/Documents/School/CMPT 470/Ex 4/output.json");
        file.write(object.toJSONString());
        file.flush();
        file.close();

        System.out.print(object);
```

Wondering if there is a simpler way in simple-json itself or if there are other libraries that better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is very simple to  use both for encoding and decoding.

The simplest way is to fill an object by simply letting the engine fill the fields using reflection to map them to the content of the file as [described here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples) : the deserialization is just the call to `gson.fromJson(json, MyClass.class);` once you created your class.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're trying to do what they call Collections in Java. First I would look at your json model. Build a class that holds the properties you listed above. Then the code will look like this.

```
 public void parseJson(){
      // Read your data into memory via String builder or however you choose. 
     List<modelthatyoubuilt> myList = new ArrayList<modelthatyoubuilt>();
     JSONArray myAwarry = new JSONArray(dataString);
     for(int i = 0; i < myAwarry.size(); i++){
     JSONObject j = myAwarry.get(i); 
     modelthatyoubuilt temp = new modelthatyoubuilt();
     temp.setProperty(j.getString("propertyname");
     //do that for the rest of the properties
     myList.add(temp); 

 }

 public int countObjects(ArrayList<modelthatyoubuilt> s){
      return s.size(); 
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. I think I figured it out in my own way but I'm having trouble writing the results to a JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class AccessData {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
        try {


            String url = "https://webapp2017sql.azurewebsites.net/api/customer";
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            //add reuqest header
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            // Send post request
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes("{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"Kamlesh\"} ");
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            //print result
            System.out.println(response.toString());


        }catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.print(ex.getMessage());

            //handle exception here

        } finally {
            //Deprecated
            //httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); 
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

## If you are new to JSON then first try below example to create json file and write data in it;

```
public class JSONWrite 

{

    public static void main(String[] args) 

    {
//      JSONObject class creates a json object

        JSONObject obj= new JSONObject();
//      provides a put function to insert the details into json object

        obj.put("name", "Dinesh");
        obj.put("phone", "0123456789");
        obj.put("Address", "BAngalore");

//      This is a JSON Array List where we Creates an array 

        JSONArray Arr = new JSONArray();

//      Add the values in newly created empty array 

        Arr.add("JSON Array List 1");
        Arr.add("JSON Array List 2");
        Arr.add("JSON Array List 3");

//      adding the array with elements to our JSON Object

        obj.put("Remark", Arr);

        try{

//          File Writer creates a file in write mode at the given location

            FileWriter file = new FileWriter(IAutoconstant.JSONLPATH);

//          Here we convert the obj data to string and put/write it inside the json file

            file.write(obj.toJSONString());
            file.flush();
        }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

## Please find below codes to read the data from above json file

//      use JsonParser to convert JSON string into Json Object

```
    JSONParser parser= new JSONParser();
```

//      parsing the JSON string inside the file that we created earlier

```
    Object obj=parser.parse(new FileReader(IAutoconstant.JSONLPATH));
```

//      Json string has been converted into JSONObject

```
    JSONObject jsonObject =(JSONObject)obj;
```

//      Display values from JSON OBject by using Keys

```
    String value1 = (String) jsonObject.get("name");

    System.out.println("value1 is "+value1);
```

//      converting the JSONObject into JSONArray as remark was an array.

```
    JSONArray arrayobject=(JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Remark");
```

//      Iterator is used to access the each element in the list

```
    Iterator<String> it = arrayobject.iterator();
```

//      loop will continue as long as there are elements in the array.

```
    while(it.hasNext())
            {
            System.out.println(it.next());
            }
}
```

Hope it help to understand the concept of json read.write